Override noticed gem delivery method
I'm using noticed Gem version 1.6 with my Rails application.
I'm trying to override the delivery method in lib/noticed/delivery_methods/fcm.rb' so when the response returns an error code other than 404, it logs and continues the loop on the devise token.
I placed my new version in lib/noticed/delivery_methods/fcm.rb
class Noticed::DeliveryMethods::Fcm < Noticed::DeliveryMethods::Base
  def deliver
    puts"****************************Overrdie is called*****************"
    device_tokens.each do |device_token|
      post("#{BASE_URI}#{project_id}/messages:send", headers: {authorization: "Bearer #{access_token}"}, json: {message: format(device_token)})
    rescue ResponseUnsuccessful => exception
      if exception.response.code == 404
        cleanup_invalid_token(device_token)
      else
        Rails.logger.error("FCM request failed with code #{exception.response.code}: #{exception.message}")
      end
    end
  end
end

yet I'm getting this error NameError (undefined local variable or method `device_tokens'
although this method is defined in the original class.

While a module and a class are closely related, they're not the same things. There's also a subtle difference in the way Ruby does lookups between nested and defined namespaces. If the nesting suggestion doesn't work, note that you can fork the gem or edit it directly with the gem-open command and make any changes directly to fcm.rb.

Also, see https://www.writesoftwarewell.com/nested-modules-in-ruby/ for an example of why Noticed::DeliveryMethods::Fcm is not actually the same as a nested class/module, and https://ruby-doc.org/3.3.4/Module.html#method-c-nesting and https://ruby-doc.org/3.3.4/Module.html#method-i-ancestors for how to test the lookup of namespaced objects.

Thank you, @engineersmnky. I tried the nesting method you suggested, but I'm still getting the same error.

Thank you @ToddA.Jacobs for the article, I did change the nesting but it had the same error, also editing the gem file directly is not the best practice as with a minor upgrade the gem file will be overridden.

I just realized you made this statement "I placed my new version in lib/noticed/delivery_methods/fcm.rb".
I believe this is why you are receiving the error because based on your file location it is overriding loading that file from the library itself.
Instead you want to place this code in the initializers directory. e.g. "config/intializers/noticed_fcm_patch.rb"
Again I would still recommend appropriate module nesting:
# config/initializers/noticed_fcm_patch.rb

module Noticed
  module DeliveryMethods
    class Fcm < Base
      def deliver
        puts"****************************Override is called*****************"
        device_tokens.each do |device_token|
          post("#{BASE_URI}#{project_id}/messages:send", headers: {authorization: "Bearer #{access_token}"}, json: {message: format(device_token)})
        rescue ResponseUnsuccessful => exception
          if exception.response.code == 404
            cleanup_invalid_token(device_token)
          else
            Rails.logger.error("FCM request failed with code #{exception.response.code}: #{exception.message}")
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end


it worked, I also needed to require the application_job class to work, thank you.
